# Stream FLV/MKV Files From a Windows Phone(Lumia 520) in Android Phone(Nexus 4)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, dlna, video-streaming, screencast

I have a Nexus 4 (Lollipop) & a Lumia 520 (Windows 8.1)

Since, Nexus has limitations of Data size & Lumia supports a microsd, Most of my Videos/movies are stored in lumia 520's SD card.

Almost all of these happen to be in flv/mkv format which unfortunately is not supported by windows phone.
There are apps which claim to support mkv in lumia but have a lot of defects in decoding. 
I tried mkv viewer,ccplayer, moli etc. but the experience is pretty disappointing.

So, I need a way to create a peer to peer network such that Lumia 520 acts as a media server & streams videos(no downloads.. all in memory as there is insufficient data space) to nexus 4(which can play these videos excellently).

There is an app in Windows store (Lumia Play To) which can cast screen to other devices.

Using BubbleUPNP on Nexus 4, I could get Nexus 4 to be seen in Lumia & works good. 
However, this approach has **two limitations :**

1) You need a separate wifi router/network to which both devices can connect.

2) Lumia Play To cannot stream mkv/flv videos.

There is also an app (Easy Transfer) for windows which shows phone files via Browser. 
This shows flv/mkv files but it does not stream videos. 
Rather, it downloads the video & that is very slow. Also, a separate wifi network is needed.

So I need a Way/Apps wherein I can create a Wifi direct network between these two devices & watch videos in nexus 4 without fully downloading them.

(The last four words might be too much to ask but if at all it is possible, that would be good.)